# Returning Multiple Row with Exact Same Values for HR1-24 Repeated the number of HR Values it should have

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am trying to link derive the values for HR1-HR25 for each `entity_name_tx`. The values should be grouped based off:

1. The Date/Day
2. The Response_Type
3. Posting_Type.

Below is the code I have thus far:

```
select
  e.entity_name_tx
 , CASE WHEN FL.FORM_LINE_ID = '4433'
    THEN 'Same-Day'
    WHEN FL.FORM_LINE_ID = '4434'
    THEN 'Daily'
    END             Posting_Type
 , ff.form_field_tx     Response_Type
 , v.data_date          Day_Of_Year
 , v.utc_offset         GMT_Offset
 , CASE WHEN v.data_Date < 100000 and v.data_date > 9999
    THEN to_Date(lpad(v.data_Date, 7, '0'), 'DDDYYYY')
    WHEN v.data_Date < 10000 
    THEN to_date(lpad(v.data_Date, 7, '00'), 'DDDYYYY')
    END              Posted_Date
 ,  MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 1
            THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
             WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 1
           THEN Value_Tx
       END) as HR1
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 2
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 2
    THEN Value_Tx
    END  )          HR2
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 3
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 3
    THEN Value_Tx
    END )            HR3
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 4
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 4
    THEN Value_Tx
    END )            HR4
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 5
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 5
    THEN Value_Tx
    END )            HR5      
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 6
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 6
    THEN Value_Tx
    END)             HR6
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 7
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 7
    THEN Value_Tx
    END)             HR7
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 8
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 8
    THEN Value_Tx
    END )            HR8
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 9
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 9
    THEN Value_Tx
    END )            HR9
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 10
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 10
    THEN Value_Tx
    END )            HR10
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 11
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 11
    THEN Value_Tx
    END   )          HR11
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 12
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 12
    THEN Value_Tx
    END )            HR12
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 13
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 13
    THEN Value_Tx
    END  )           HR13
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 14
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 14
    THEN Value_Tx
    END  )           HR14
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 15
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 15
    THEN Value_Tx
    END )            HR15
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 16
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 16
    THEN Value_Tx
    END  )           HR16
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 17
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 17
    THEN Value_Tx
    END  )           HR17
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 18
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 18
    THEN Value_Tx
    END  )           HR18
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 19
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 19
    THEN Value_Tx
    END  )           HR19
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 20
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 20
    THEN Value_Tx
    END  )           HR20
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 21
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 21
    THEN Value_Tx
    END  )           HR21
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 22
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 22
    THEN Value_Tx
    END  )           HR22
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 23
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 23
    THEN Value_Tx
    END  )           HR23
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 24
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 24
    THEN Value_Tx
    END  )           HR24
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 25
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('NG', 'D', 'TI', 'DF') and v.HR_NUM = 25
    THEN Value_Tx
    END  )           HR25
 from entity e 
  inner join survey_respondent sr on e.entity_id = sr.entity_id
  inner join submission s on s.survey_respondent_id = sr.survey_respondent_id
  inner join submission_value sv on s.submission_id = sv.submission_id
  inner join value v on  v.value_id = sv.value_id
  inner join form_field ff on sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id
  inner join form_line fl on ff.form_line_id = fl.form_line_id;
```

When I run this script I get something that looks like this:

```
 Entity_Name_Tx  Posting_Type  Response_Type    Day_Of_Year  GMT_OFFSET   POSTED_DATE   HR1         HR2         HR3         HR4         HR5         HR6         HR7         HR8         HR9         HR10         HR11         HR12         HR13         HR14         HR15         HR16         HR17         HR18         HR19         HR20         HR21         HR22         HR23         HR24         HR25
Cherry Street   Daily   UTCD    12015   4   01-JAN-15                                                                                           08-03-18 13:02:17   
Cherry Street   Daily   UTC0    592014  5       08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   
Cherry Street   Daily   UTC0    592014  5       08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   
Cherry Street   Daily   UTC0    592014  5       08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   
Cherry Street   Daily   UTC0    592014  5       08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   
Cherry Street   Daily   UTC0    592014  5       08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   
Cherry Street   Daily   UTC0    592014  5       08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   
Cherry Street   Daily   UTC0    592014  5       08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   
Cherry Street   Daily   UTC0    592014  5       08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18   08-03-18 13:02:18
```

I'm trying to get just one row for this one particular HR1 value but it seems to be populating every column/row with this value. (I'm thinking that perhaps my joins are incorrect)? Please let me know what other information I can provide.

thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have code that you're having to type repeatedly, it's probably a good place to look for a way to refactor. That might be a good place for a CTE with a PIVOT.

Comment: Also, why is `data_Date` not actually a date but an integer? That might make part of this query a lot easier if you can change it.

Comment: And finally, can you provide some sample data to play with?